# how do i find out an elements index?

Tags: jquery, console

Hello I am trying to find out a dom elements index and log it in the console.
How do I find out an elements index and log it in the console in chromes dev tools using jQuery?

Comment: Index relative to what? Its siblings? The matched set of elements?

Comment: if `console.log($(element).index())` isn't what you want, then you question might be insufficiently detailed.

Comment: You will have to define what you mean by "index" before we can help you.

Comment: I normally see this question associated with .each http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get element `index` like this:

```
$('#elementID').index();
```

and you look it in the `console` like this:

```
console.log($('#elementID').index())
```

For example, lets say you have three div's:

```
<div>First div</div>
<div>Second div</div>
<div>Third div</div>
```

you can get get the `div` index on click and also see in the console:

```
$("div").click(function () {

  // this is the dom element clicked
  var index = $("div").index(this);
  console.log("That was div index #" + index);
});
```

Comment: that is the correct answer thank you I do believe @dstroy got there first though!